# How to create a derived attribute in DDL

Tags: sqlplus, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE Matches
(
mID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
date DATE NOT NULL,
location CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
teamA CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
goalsForA INTEGER,
pointsA INTEGER,
teamB, CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
goalsForB INTEGER,
pointsB INTEGER,
/*
M1: The match number must be under 65
*/
CONSTRAINT M1 CHECK (mID < 65),
/*
M2: location must refer to stadiumName in the Locations. 
*/
CONSTRAINT M2 FOREIGN KEY (location) REFERENCES Stadiums (stadiumName)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
/*
M3: 
*/
CONSTRAINT M3 ()
)
```

okay so I need to make it so pointsA and pointsB is calculated by goalsForA and goalsForB. If goalsForA = goalsForB then pointsA and pointsB get 1 each. If goalsForA > goalsForB, then pointsA gets 3 added and vice versa for B. My professor never taught us about how to do this, and I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, don't store what you can calculate.  Make a table without pointsA and pointsB, then make a view of the table with calculated columns.

Comment: How do you make a view of a table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436413/oracle-calculate-two-values-and-show-result-in-a-view